# Remove transmission cooler lines K1500 '00

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission

What is the trick from removing the cooler lines from the transmission on my 2000 k1500?

I know how to disconnect the lines. I just don't know how to reach the clip on the lower connection on the transmission. There just isn't room.

I'm not removing the transmission.

Any ideas?

Just in case anyone is wondering how to disconnect the lines:

```
Method 1:
Slide the blade of a small flat screwdriver along the line into the connector.
Move the blade around the tube until the small metal clip to poke out.
Sometime it will stay poking out if not just leave the driver there and use another small flat driver or some pliers to pull the clip off. 
**DON'T force it.** Just work the clip around and off.
Then just pull the line out.

Method 2:
Slide a small flat screwdriver in the grove of the receptacle at the open end of the clip. With a small amount of pressure the clip will come up and out.
 **DON'T force it.** Just work the clip around and off.
Then just pull the line out.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a special tool that makes this job possible.

1. Snap it around the line.
2. Press the three crowns into the fitting.
3. Twist the tool so the three crowns push the clip out of the fitting.
4. Pull the line and the tool out.

There isn't a lot of room up there. With three or four tries it will work.

[image]